# Comparison and indexing series of arrays with length > 1

Tags: arrays, pandas, indexing, comparison, series

Title sounds more complicated than the facts really are. Given the data

```
data = [
    np.array(['x'], dtype='object'),
    np.array(['y'], dtype='object'),
    np.array(['z'], dtype='object'),
    np.array(['x', 'z', 'y'], dtype='object'),
    np.array(['y', 'x'], dtype='object'),
]    

s = pd.Series(data)
```

I would like to retrieve to elements of `s` where `s == np.array(['x'])`. The obvious way

```
c = np.array(['x'])
s[s==c]
```

does not work, since there is a ValueError in the comparison, complaining that "'Lengths must match to compare', (5,), (1,)". I also tried

```
s[s=='x']
```

which only works if the elements of `s` have all exactly one element themselves.

Is there a way to retrieve all elements of `s`, where `s == c`, *without* converting the elements to string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we use a loop, I think this is a simpler way.

```
out = s[s.apply(lambda x: x.tolist() == ['x'])]
```

out:

```
0    [x]
dtype: object
```

---

**checking example**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = [
    np.array(['x'], dtype='object'),
    np.array(['y'], dtype='object'),
    np.array(['z'], dtype='object'),
    np.array(['x', 'z', 'y'], dtype='object'),
    np.array(['y', 'x'], dtype='object'),
]  * 1000000
s1 = pd.Series(data1)
```

5000000 rows

```
c = np.array(['x'], dtype='object')
d = c.tolist()
```

chk speed

```
>>> import timeit
>>> %timeit s1[s1.apply(lambda x: x.tolist() == d)]

1.38 s ± 106 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
>>> %timeit s1[[np.array_equal(a, c) for a in s1]]

22.2 s ± 754 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> eq_c = partial(np.array_equal, c)
>>> %timeit s1[map(eq_c, s1)]


21.8 s ± 449 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Shorter syntax, not simpler in terms of complexity. Converting an array to list is expensive. In contrast `np.array_equal` (as I suggested) first compares the dimensions and immediately returns `False` if the shapes don't match. Here you convert to list regardless of the future use of the list. I guess the equivalent python code would be `c = ['x'] ; s.apply(lambda x: len(x)==len(c) and x.tolist()==c)` and even here this is still more expensive that an array comparison.

Comment: @mozway The reason I think this is a simpler way is as follows. syntax is simpler and code is easier to think about, can be solved within pandas, and result is not slow.

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension with [`numpy.array_equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html):

```
c = np.array(['x'])

out = s[[np.array_equal(a, c) for a in s]]
```

Alternative with a [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3.9/library/functools.html#functools.partial) function if you need to do this repeatedly (for the shorter syntax):

```
from functools import partial
eq_c = partial(np.array_equal, c)

out = s[map(eq_c, s)]
```

Output:

```
0    [x]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Surely there must be a vectorized way of doing this?

Comment: @Nick I don't think so, you would need to first convert the ensemble of arrays into a common structure which would be more expensive that looping in the first place.

Comment: mmm... yeah I guess so...

Comment: @Nick you can always use `eq_c = np.vectorize(lambda a: np.array_equal(a, c)) ; df[eq_c(s)]`, but this remains a loop.